# Editing the coding of QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, editing

I’d like to try the fix mentioned in this article:

https://github.com/KIOS-Research/ImportPhotos/issues/105

Can someone provide some pointers on how can I edit that line of coding for the ImportPhoto plugin?

Comment: Incase someone comes a long this thread, for me the plug in was located at:

C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\*****\python\plugins\ImportPhotos

Also, I was able to use notepad to edit that line of text!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Navigate to Plugin folder (Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder).
- Go to `python/plugins/ImportPhotos` folder.
- Open `ImportPhotos.py` file.
- Find `rel_path = self.selected_folder + os.path.basename(photo_path)` under `get_geo_infos_from_photo` method.
- And change it to `rel_path = os.path.relpath(photo_path,start=os.path.dirname(self.dlg.out.text()))`